# ¿Cómo seleccionar los datos solo de algunas tuplas?

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de tuplas por ejemplo:

```
x = [('46388', 'ERRE', 'X'), ('157772', 'JOTA', 'X'), 
     ('38597659', 'JOTA', 'X'), ('38600875', 'ERRE', 'R')]
```

Y siempre me han hecho falta coger todos los elementos de las tuplas pero ahora sólo quiero coger los IDs donde la segunda posición de la tupla sea JOTA de tal forma que crease una nueva lista:

```
y = 157772, 38597659
```

yo hacia algo asi:

```
    if str(content[1]) == 'X':
        X = ",".join(str(content[0])
                     for x in Y)
```

Pero claro eso me recorre todas las tuplas y yo solo quiero las que tenga lo de la primera condición.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que aprendas sobre [comprensión de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), es una forma súper concisa y clara (cuando te acostumbras) de manipular todo tipo de colecciones de datos. En tu caso, lo harías para filtrar tuplas:

```
nueva_lista = [tupla[0] for tupla in x if tupla[1] == 'JOTA']
```

Básicamente se lee: obtener el 1er elemento de cada tupla de la lista x, siempre que el segundo elemento de dicha tupla sea `JOTA`.

```
print(nueva_lista)

['157772', '38597659']
```

Comment: mucha sgracias!! me lo revisaré me ha funcionado a la perfección!

Comment: @Sergio, si _te ha funcionado_, lo que corresponde es aceptar la pregunta, además de votar a favor por ella. Si no sabes como hacerlo, te invito a re-hacer el [tour]. Más información en [Qué hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).